# Cannot get token from Opencart API

Tags: angular, http, post, token, opencart

I am working on my angular app and i want to use opencart REST API for some reason. As docs says firstly i have to get token from API. Heres code from docs:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()

username = 'Default'
key='L3MYyzlYMRL8gBcpCm6CdrVarFUXtPORZkJKP7vgaY8M8EIZWOr3EJxq'
# Actually, key is 256 character-long

s.post(
    'http://myopencart.example.com/index.php?route=api/login',
    data={'username':username, 'key':key}
).text
```

Here is my angular app code:

```
getToken() {
    return this.http.post(
      this.config.getUrl() + '/login',
      {
        username: this.config.getUserName(),
        key: this.config.getKey()
      },
      {
        responseType: 'text'
      }
    );
  }
```

For some reason i got this error message:

```
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: api_token in <b>/var/www/html/opencart/catalog/controller/startup/startup.php</b> on line <b>45</b><b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: username in <b>/var/www/html/opencart/catalog/controller/api/login.php</b> on line <b>11</b><b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: key in <b>/var/www/html/opencart/catalog/controller/api/login.php</b> on line <b>11</b>[]
```

What do i do wrong?

Comment: If you are working with OC3, the token you can get in controller file like this: `$data['user_token'] = $this->session->data['user_token'];` After you can call it in corresponding TWIG: `{{ user_token }}`

Comment: @K.B. Yes, im working with OC3. I need to make API request work, not only get token. Maybe something wrong with http request?

Comment: If his request in admin side your url should be:`http://myopencart.example.com/index.php?route=api/login&user_token={{ user_token }}` and of course you should define elements where you got an error in corresponding controller file.